# using JParameter in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm thinking of using JParams to store the last visited date of a
certain page in a Joomla 1.7.1 site. So in the code I'm doing something like:

```
$last_run       = $params->get('last_visit', '2000-01-01');
// set last_run to current run time
$params->set('last_visit', $now);
```

The problem is obviously that the newly set value for last_visit
doesn't get stored, though it does get set.

Is there some way to store the params, without going through a DB
query? Thanks

Comment: which version of Joomla is that? 1.5 or 1.6+

Comment: 1.7.1-- sorry, should have made that more clear.

Comment: OK. I have another question, by page do you mean Article or Menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example solution of your problem, but bare in mind this is for Joomla 1.5

```
// Get instance of the table object of your component
$table =& JTable::getInstance( 'mytable');
// Set the item, this could be Article ID for example
$table->load($id);
// Load the parameters through JParameter
$params   = new JParameter($table->params);
$params->set($key,$value);
$table->params = $params->toString();
// Save to database
$table->store();
```

All this could be done in a plugin if you don't want to alter the core of the component otherwise if it's a component the you are building you can set this in the Model of the component and call it from the controller on every save.

Comment: @infinity-- thanks for the tip, but again, this would simply be setting params for a table, not for the component's params as registered in the jos_extensions table (jos_components in Joomla 1.5x), right?

Comment: According to the Joomla core team, there's no way to do what I was thinking was possible (eg. using a Jparameter::store() type of function). 

You need to do basically what @infinity says above.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a content Plugin which gets trigerred on view.

```
public function onContentPrepare(...) {
   ...store hit date into table...
}
```

Good thing about that method is you don't need any core hacks.

Comment: Thanks Mike-- but I'm not trying to save a value to a DB, for various reasons-- I want to store an actual parameter.

Comment: I see, but even then it is wise not to hack the core and use a plugin. If you plan not to do a plugin you could create an content override for the item page and store the new param from there (no hacks again).
`components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default.php`

Comment: ok, but the question is "how to store the param"? I expected there to be some kind of Jparam::store() function to do this.

Comment: see infinitys answer for that.