# How to set plugin params programatically? (Joomla 1.7)

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

Is there any way to set a plugin parameter programatically from within a plugin?

I've tried:

```
$this->params->set('param_name', 'value');
```

This doesn't work, although many forums suggests it should.

Comment: The code above actually sets the param value, but not persistant. I've found at way to save it using db-query, but there must be some other way.

Comment: If it's a JParameter, then no there isn't a way.  See [this similar question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070213/using-jparameter-in-joomla

Answer (score 0):

After the parameter is set you need to parse all parameters into string value and store in `jos_extensions` table.

Don't try to use `$params->toString();` as this is `JParameters` object. You need to go through it manually.